# ¿como leo funciones en un componente angular con typescript o javascript usando el evento onmouseover en mi html?

Tags: javascript, html5, angular, typescript

no puedo leer las funciones que coloco en mi component.ts desde mi component.html utilizando el evento onmouseover

ya intente colocarlo dentro de el constructor también dentro del ngOnInit y fuera de ambos pero no funciona también intente enlazar el archivo .js con mi component.html y con el index.html de mi proyecto y sigue saliendo el mismo error este:

```
uncaught ReferenceError: aler is not defined
at HTMLAnchorElement.onmouseover (Juego:15)
```

donde aler es una función en mi componen.ts y juego:15 es la linea donde la llamo

```
function aler() {
    alert("fg");
}
```

y la llama en mi componente.html de esta manera en la etiqueta a de html

```
<a onmouseover="aler();">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a (mouseenter)="aler()">
```

Te anexo esta referencia: [Angular event binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#event-binding)